# Вывести версию приложения в левое меню

Tags: android

Как в левое меню вместо почты вывеси версию приложения? Собственно как узнать версию приложения я знаю.

```
try {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
    txtVersion.setText("Версия: " + packageInfo.versionName);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но как вывести не знаю. Присвоил TextView в левом меню id и нашел через findViewById и пытался присвоить текст приложение падает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы реализуете "левое меню"? Покажите что пишет, когда падает

Comment: Левое меню само появляется я выбираю шаблон Navigation Drawable

Comment: Как и попросили выше, добавьте в вопрос сообщение из logcat с которым падает приложение. И добавть код в котором вы находите TextView и задаете ему текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того что бы взять версию не стоит использовать `PackageManager`, для этого существует автоматически генерируемый при сборке `BuildConfig`.

Ответ на вопрос:

`TextView textView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textView);
 textView.setText("Version: " + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);`

[image: результат]

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало. Только я немного переделал первую строчку TextView txtHeaderVersion = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.txtHeaderVersion);

Comment: Про `PackageManager` есть один нюанс. Если левое меню будет реализовано в библиотеке, то `BuildConfig`, в отличие от `PackageManager` будет выдавать значение версии библиотеки, а не использующего её приложения, т.к. `BuildConfig` поля не переопределяются приложением, в отличие от, например, ресурсов.